# How to force a status 200 on each route change in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, server-side-rendering

I am working on a decoupled angular app. We are using SRR and have discovered that we only get a status 200 on the initial load and subsequent pages don't get recognized by googles crawlers.

This makes sense, when we get the document from the server it shows 200. But when we navigate using the browser, there is no request sent so there is no status to respond with.
We tried an interceptor but got an error like: `The response is already set`.

How can we set a status for each of our angular routes so google can crawl our site correctly?

I have seen no examples showing how to remedy the status issue after SRR has returned the document

Comment: This is not needed really. The google bot isn’t a normal user that clicks through your site, it just requests individual urls from your server. Also, if you look at your ssr generated source, you’ll see ‘normal’ href links there. So as long as every route of your site is directly requestable from the server, you’re fine.

Comment: @MikeOne definitely, thanks for the response. Unfortunately our business and marketing units are telling us that google is not indexing our subsequent pages and it needs to be fixed.

Comment: If you request an internal page directly, can you see the rendered content in the source? If yes, there is nothing more you can do from that respect. If internal pages are not crawled or indexed, you can help google by providing a sitemap. Also, check google search console to confirm crawlability and index status.